# How to compare string changes per time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I had a dataset with monthly record per client as below. I would like to check if the FREQ was changed be the end of quarter compared with the value in the beginning of each quarter by client, and append a new column as indicator to show the changes or not. Not sure if there is any way to realize this, thanks for advise!

============

```
  Month        Client      FREQ   
 2019-01-01       A        Weekly
 2019-02-01       A        Weekly
 2019-03-01       A        Monthly
 2019-01-01       B        Weekly
 2019-02-01       B        Weekly
 2019-03-01       B        Weekly
```

The expected output would be:

```
  Month        Client      FREQ        Changes 
 2019-01-01       A        Weekly
 2019-02-01       A        Weekly
 2019-03-01       A        Monthly      Yes
 2019-01-01       B        Weekly
 2019-02-01       B        Weekly
 2019-03-01       B        Weekly        No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way playing with the groupby object: `GroupBy.tail` and `GroupBy.nunique`

```
g = df.groupby('Client')
df.loc[g.tail(1).index, 'Changes'] = g.FREQ.nunique().ne(1)\
                                                     .map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})\
                                                     .tolist()
```

---

```
        Month Client     FREQ Changes
0  2019-01-01      A   Weekly     NaN
1  2019-02-01      A   Weekly     NaN
2  2019-03-01      A  Monthly     Yes
3  2019-01-01      B   Weekly     NaN
4  2019-02-01      B   Weekly     NaN
5  2019-03-01      B   Weekly      No
```